# How to set a image to button which is created programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using -setImage on NSButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929409/using-setimage-on-nsbutton)

```
I created a button using following code .


    NSView *superview = [_window contentView];
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 200, 100);
    button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setTitle:@"Click me!"];
```

so how can I set a image to this button ?

Comment: Did you even bother looking at the `NSButton` class reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
- (void)setImage:(NSImage *)anImage
```

e.g.:

```
[button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: You're code is iOS, not OS X!