# NSButton setImage not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsbutton

I am trying to change the image of my nsbutton for my application. 
I have searched and found a couple of ways to do so but none of them are working for me at the moment.

I have looked at the following solutions :

[How to set NSButton background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514258/how-to-set-nsbutton-background-image)
[Using -setImage on NSButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929409/using-setimage-on-nsbutton)

I have a routine that is called when I click the button :

```
- (IBAction)pauseResumeButtonAction:(id)sender
```

{
    IAgentInterface* agentInterface = ioc::Container::Resolve();

```
if (self.pauseResumeSwitch == PauseResumeSwitch::PAUSE)
{
    //if ready to pause do this
    AgentCommand cmd( AGENT_CMD_PAUSE_SERVICE);
    agentInterface->sendAgentCommand( cmd );
    self.pauseResumeSwitch = PauseResumeSwitch::RESUME;

    [self.pauseResumeButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"]];
}
else if (self.pauseResumeSwitch == PauseResumeSwitch::RESUME)
{
    //else if ready to resume do this
    AgentCommand cmd( AGENT_CMD_RESUME_SERVICE);
    agentInterface->sendAgentCommand( cmd );
    self.pauseResumeSwitch = PauseResumeSwitch::PAUSE;

    [self.pauseResumeButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"resume.png"]];
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

can someone please help me find my mistake ? 
it will be of great help

thanks in advance :)

Comment: the style changes the way that the button's image works, it may only just display an image if it is in custom style

Comment: the style drop down includes different styles such as a radio button or a checkbox button

Comment: self.pauseResumeButton <- did you checked this is not null?

Comment: I am not sure but I tired to debug. Placed a breakpoint at this code and clicked the button. when I reach this place, inside the debug area I try to expand the self variable but nothing shows inside that variable. then I try to print the self variable in the console and I get the following outputs :

Comment: (lldb) p self
error: cannot define category for undefined class 'PanelController'
error: cannot find interface declaration for 'PanelController'
note: forward declaration of class here
note: forward declaration of class here
error: 2 errors parsing expression

Comment: (lldb) p self.pauseResumeButton
error: cannot define category for undefined class 'PanelController'
error: cannot find interface declaration for 'PanelController'
error: member access into incomplete type 'PanelController'
note: forward declaration of class here
note: forward declaration of class here
note: forward declaration of class here
error: 3 errors parsing expression